# Find all the function such that...

Tags: functions, derivatives, convex-analysis

First correct me if the question is not new .

Let $0<x<1$ or $x>1$ then find all the  functions $f(x)$ such that :

On $(1,\infty)$ the function $f(x)$ is convex , have only one extrema wich is a minimum and $f(x_{min})=x_{min}>0$

On $(0,1)$ the function $f(x)$ is concave , have only one extrema wich is a maximum and $f(x_{max})=x_{max}>0$

There is the trivial function .More curiously I have found the function $\left(\frac{\left(\ln\left(\frac{0.5}{x}\right)\right)}{\frac{1}{x}-1}\right)$ related to the Lambert's function .It's not hard to show it in this particular case .We have also $\left(\frac{\left(\ln\left(\frac{a}{x}\right)\right)}{\frac{1}{x}-1}\right)$ with $0<a<1$

How to find it in the general case ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $g \colon (1,\infty) \to \mathbb R$ be a convex function with a unique minimizer
$x_{\min}$ (and no other extrema) and let $h \colon (0,1) \to \mathbb R$ be a concave function with a unique maximizer $x_{\max}$ (and no other extrema).

Then, we can define $f \colon (0,\infty)\setminus\{1\} \to \mathbb R$ via
$$
f(x) := \begin{cases}
g(x) - g(x_{\min}) + x_{\min} & \text{if } x \in (1,\infty), \\
h(x) - h(x_{\max}) + x_{\max} & \text{if } x \in (0,1).
\end{cases}
$$
It is also clear that all functions $f$ can be constructed in this way.

Now, it remains to fix some convex and concave functions. Since you asked for 'radically' different functions, we can drop in some radical signs:
$$
g(x) = \frac14 - \sqrt{x},
\qquad\text{and}\qquad
h(x) = \sqrt{x} - x.$$

Comment: First thanks for you try .First point you have inversed the convexity on the two interval.Second point your definition of $f(x)$ is too general for me can you be more specific or it isn't possible ?Can you add a concret example in your answer? I think to accept your answer if you examine my questions.

Comment: by concret example I mean an example radically different from mine .Again, thanks!